# Return object of multiple counts

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to query a document and return a single object that lists three counts of 3 different scenarios in a single key. Here's how the collection is organized:

```
{
  response_main:{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: "topics"
  },
  response_in: {
    type: Number
  }
}
```

The `response_in` key needs to be sorted as to whether it is a 0,1 or 2. The way I am currently solving this problem is:

```
Collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {response_main: mainTopic._id}},
  {$group: {
    _id: {
      $cond: {if: {$eq: ["$response_in", 0]}, then: "agree", else:{
        $cond: {if: {$eq: ["$response_in", 1]}, then: "neutral", else:{
          $cond: {if: {$eq: ["$response_in", 2]}, then: "disagree", else:false}
        }
      }
    }, count: {$sum: 1}
  }}
], callback);
```

The format the data is returned in is an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "agree",
    "count": 14
  },
  {
    "_id": "neutral",
    "count": 12
  },
  {
    "_id": "disagree",
    "count": 16
  }
]
```

However, I'd prefer the returned object to look like this:

```
{
  "agree": 14,
  "neutral": 12,
  "disagree": 16,
}
```

Is there another way I could structure my query to achieve this more succinct result?

Comment: I would suggest you answering your own question or removing the question then.

Answer (score 0):

Reformatted the data prior to sending the JSON response, all is well now.